# Which event to listen when DOM rendered is shifted

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have a strange bug I am trying to fix. My window is fixed i.e. it has a header and footer which is always top and bottom. I also have an iframe component which floats on the window.

The problem occurs when the focus goes to a form element inside the iframe. The browser "moves" the rendered DOM up to show the focussed form element in the iframe.

How can I detect this "move" of DOM. The browser size remains the same and there is no resize event.

Comment: Any specific reason you are using an iframe instead of a in document element? its creating an isolated scope (security-, origin- wise), thereby changing the behaviors and capabilities of interaction between owner browser root element and iframe contained elements.

Comment: Yeh, Its an iframe due to historical reasons and I cannot change it now.

Comment: That should be a `scroll` event, shouldn't it?